# Derivative of a norm of the vector valued function: $ \nabla_{\beta} \| f(X \beta)\|_{2}^{2}$

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

Let $f$ be ReLU function, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^d$.
What is the derivative of $ \nabla_{\beta} \| f(X \beta)\|_{2}^{2}$ ?

I think, by chain rule, $\nabla_\beta \| f(X\beta) \|^{2}_{2} = 2 \nabla f(X\beta) f(X\beta) = 2 X^{\top} f'(X\beta) f(X\beta)$.
But, the matrix size does'nt match.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\t{\theta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Define the vector
$$y=X\b \quad\implies\quad dy=X\,d\b$$
and the scalar ReLu and Step functions
$$\eqalign{
f(z)
 &= \begin{cases}
z \quad{\rm if}\;z\ge 0 \\
0 \quad{\rm if}\;z<0 \\
\end{cases}
\qquad\qquad
g(z) = \frac{df}{dz}
 &= \begin{cases}
1 \quad{\rm if}\;z\ge 0 \\
0 \quad{\rm if}\;z<0 \\
\end{cases}
\\
}$$
Apply them elementwise to the vector $y$ to generate the vectors
$$f=f(y),\qquad\qquad g=g(y) \qquad$$
Then the function in this question becomes
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= f:f \\
d\phi &= 2f:df \\
 &= 2f:\LR{g\odot dy} \\
 &= 2\LR{f\odot g}:X\,d\b \\
 &= 2X^T\LR{f\odot g}:d\b \\
\grad{\phi}{\b} &= 2X^T\LR{f\odot g} \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and
$(:)$ the trace/Frobenius product. These products have the following definitions
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
   \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:\LR{B\odot C} &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij}
   \;=\; \LR{A\odot B}:C \\
}$$
These matrix products can also be applied to vectors by treating them as rectangular matrices with one column.